# Send dynamic Fields data from one component to another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive form to dynamically create some fields, these fields are sort of nested dynamic fields first I am creating an array and then according to size of that newly created array I am generating some other input fields after getting the data into the fields now I want to send the data to another component.I was trying to use viewProviders option here but for some reasons its not working here.
Basically I want to achieve this.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xusdev
***SecondComponent.html***

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicForm" (ngSubmit)=" returnVariantTo()" >
  <div class="variants-attr-row mt-1">

    <div>
      <label>
        <div *ngFor="let t of a.controls; let i = index"  class="field-heading">Attribute (e.g. 
Colour)
      <div [formGroup]="t" >
        <select formControlName="attribute"  class="attr-dropdown">
          <option *ngFor="let value of attribute" [ngValue]="value.id">
            {{ value.name }}
          </option>
        </select>     

      <div class="flex-one">
        <label>
         <div class="field-heading">Value (e.g. Red, Blue, Green)</div>
       <p-chips inputStyleClass="full-width theme-input"  max=5  formControlName="value" ></p-chips>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div> 
      </div>
     </label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="add-variantes-row">
<div>
<a>
<div class="add-variant-btn"> + </div>
   <div class="ml-2 pointer" (click)="addAttitubute()">Add Variant</div>
</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn theme-btn " *ngIf="save">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="variant-accordion-container" *ngFor="let data of d.controls; let i = index">

<div class="variant-heading-row">
  <div class="variant-att-first-col">Variant Name</div>
  <div class="variant-att-second-col">Retail Price</div>
  <div class="variant-att-third-col">Cost Price</div>
  </div>
<div  class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
   <div [formGroup]="data">
   <div class="card">
   <div id="headingOne">                                           
   <div class="variant-accordion-row">
   <div class="variant-att-first-col" >Mobile</div>
   <div class="variant-att-second-col"><input type="number" formControlName="retailPrice"></div>
   <div class="variant-att-third-col"><input type="number" formControlName="costPrice" ></div>
   </div>
    </div>
     </div>
      </div> 
       </div>   
</form>
```

***SecondComponent.ts***

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'product-variant.component.html',
    selector: 'product-variant',
    providers:[FormBuilder, AttributeService],
    viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class ProductVariantComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('content1') private content1;
    @ViewChild('content2') private content2;
    array=[];
    value=[];
    save= false;
    attribute = new Attribute();
    dynamicForm;
    submitted = false;
    variant = new Variant();
    @Output() returnVariant= new EventEmitter();
    isCollapsed = true;
    constructor(
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private variantSerice: VariantService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private attributeService: AttributeService,
        @Host() private parentFor: FormGroupDirective 
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() {

        this.dynamicForm = this.parentFor.form;
        this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            attributes: new FormArray([]),
            data: new FormArray([])
        });

    }
    get f() { return this.dynamicForm.controls; }
    get a() { return this.f.attributes as FormArray; }
    get d() { return this.f.data as FormArray; }

    addAttitubute(){

        this.attributeService.getAttributes().subscribe(response =>{
            this.save = true;
            this.attribute=response;
            if(this.a.length < 3){
                this.a.push(this.formBuilder.group({
                    attribute: new FormControl (""),
                    value: new FormControl("")
                }));
            } else {
                console.log("Cant add more");
            }
        }) 

    }

    returnVariantTo() {
    this.array=null
    let obj=[];
    let temp=[];
    obj.push(this.dynamicForm.value.attributes);
    obj.forEach(x=>{
     x.forEach(y=>{
         temp.push(y.value);
     })
    })

    this.array = this.allPossibleCases(temp);
    this.createForm(this.array);
    console.log(this.dynamicForm.value);
    }
    // this.returnVariant.emit(this.variant)

    createForm(arr:any[]){
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            this.d.push(this.formBuilder.group({
                retailPrice: ['', Validators.required],
                costPrice: ['', Validators.required],
                startingInventory: ['', Validators.required],
                reorderLevel: ['', Validators.required],
                reorderQuantity: ['', Validators.required],
                tax: ['',Validators.required]
            }));
        }
    }
    allPossibleCases(arr) {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
          return [];
        } 
      else if (arr.length ===1){
      return arr[0];
      }
      else {
          let result = [];
          let allCasesOfRest = this.allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1)); 
          for (var c in allCasesOfRest) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
              result.push(arr[0][i] + allCasesOfRest[c]);
            }
          }
          return result;
        }

      }


}
```

***FirstComponent.html***

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="detailsForm"> 
   <product-variant></product-variant>
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>
```

***FirstComponent.ts***

```
@Component({
templateUrl: 'product-add.component.html',
 providers:[BarcodeService, VariantService],
 viewProviders:[{provide:ControlContainer,useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]

})
@Injectable()
export class ProductAddComponent implements OnInit{
detailsForm = new FormGroup({});
constructor(
  ) { }
ngOnInit() {}
 onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.detailsForm.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to communicate between two child components. Is that right?

Comment: Actually there are these two component and I want to send data form data from second to first because there is only one submit button and that is in first component

Comment: Basically I want to achieve this but idk whats missing here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xusdev

Comment: So this second is a parent or a child component of first?

Comment: second is child and first is parent

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you want to communicate from `child` to `parent` component you should be using `EventEmitter`.

**Child.component.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() emitEventToParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
this.emitEventToParent.emit("{valule to be emitted}");
```

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<app-child (emitEventToParent)="captureEvent($event)"></app-child>
```

**Parent.Component.ts**

```
captureEvent(value){
 //Your logic goes here
}
```